# Prove $1-\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{5}-\frac{1}{6}-\frac{1}{7}+\cdots$ converges.

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis

Consider the series:

$1-\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{5}-\frac{1}{6}-\frac{1}{7}+\cdots$

Is it convergent?

I believe I need to find a way to split the terms into additive and subtraction terms, however I'm not sure how to do this and as a result prove the outcome.

Comment: Are the minus and plusses always in groups of 2?  Or is the pattern more complicated?

Comment: @MJD Always in pairs

Comment: Alternating series test shows that it is convergent.

Answer (score 4):

The series is given by
$$1 + \sum_{k=1}^\infty (-1)^k \left(\frac1{2k} + \frac1{2k+1}\right)$$
Assuming convergence we split it up into
$$1 + \sum_{k=1}^\infty (-1)^k \frac1{2k} + \sum_{k=1}^\infty (-1)^k \frac1{2k+1}$$
Both parts converge due to leibniz and thus their sum converges as well.

---

Note that pulling apart series is not allowed in general, but since we were able to see that the individual parts converge, we *were* allowed to do it. To see the problem, look at the "identity"
$$-\ln 2 = \sum_{i=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^i}i "=" \sum_{i=1}^\infty \frac1{2i} - \sum_{i=1}^\infty \frac1{2i-1} "=" \infty - \infty$$

Answer (score 4):

The partial sums of 
$$1-\left(\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3}\right)+\left(\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{5}\right)-\left(\frac{1}{6}+\frac{1}{7}\right) \cdots\tag{1}$$
converge by the Alternating Series Test.  Suppose that they converge to $a$.

The partial sum of our **original** series, up to the term $\pm \frac{1}{n}$, differs from a partial sum of series (1) by at most $\frac{1}{n}$. So the partial sums of the original series also converge to $a$.

Comment: I assume you mean  that the *nth* partial sum of the original series is within $\frac{1}{n}$ of every partial sum of rearranged series. But how do you show that?

Comment: Let $s_n$ be the $n$-th partial sum of original, and $t_k$ be $k$-th partial sum of modified series, which has about half as many terms. If $n$ is odd, $s_n=t_{(n-1)/2}$. If $n$ is even, then $s_n=t_{n/2}\pm \frac{1}{n}$. So since $(t_k)$ converges, so does (s_n)$, and to same sum.

Comment: So for every partial sum $s_{n}$, there exists a partial sum $t_{k}$ such that $s_{n} \le t_{k} \pm \frac{1}{n}$? That makes a lot more sense that what I though you were saying. And is the other answer in this thread wrong because it assumes right off the bat that the two conditionally convergent series are equivalent?

Comment: The other answer is right. It differs from mine in that it uses more (correct) machinery about series.

Comment: The second line of the other answer say that $$1- \frac{1}{2} - \frac{1}{3} + \frac{1}{4} + \frac{1}{5} - \ldots = 1-(\frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{3}) + (\frac{1}{4} + \frac{1}{5} ) + \ldots$$ That's immediately justified? Aren't you rearranging the terms of a conditionally convergent series?

Comment: There is no real rearranging involved. A straightforward generalization of my estimate shows that we can always do the rebracketing. The same idea shows that "finite rearranging" (nothing moves more than $C$ places) is OK.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** We have the two series
$$
\tan^{-1}(1)=1-\frac13+\frac15-\frac17+\dots
$$
and
$$
\frac12\log(2)=0+\frac12-\frac14+\frac16-\frac18+\dots
$$
which converge by the [Alternating Series Test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alternating_series_test). The term-by-term difference of two convergent series is convergent.

Answer (score 1):

\begin{align}
\dots &= \left(1 - \frac{1}{3} + \frac{1}{5} - \frac{1}{7} + \dots \right) - \left(\frac{1}{2} - \frac{1}{4} + \frac{1}{6} - \dots \right) \\
&= \left(1 - \frac{1}{3} + \frac{1}{5} - \frac{1}{7} + \dots \right)- \frac{1}{2} \, \left(1 - \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{3} - \dots \right) \\
&=   \tan^{-1}(1) - \frac{1}{2} \, \log\left(1+1\right)= \frac{\pi}{4} - \frac{1}{2} \, \log(2)
\end{align}

Comment: I think there is an error in the last line. It should be log(1+1) and not log(1-1/2). For the OP: these are the taylor expansions of the functions, cf. Maclaurin Series [http://mathworld.wolfram.com/MaclaurinSeries.html]

Comment: Two corrections: It's spelled _pi_, not _pie_ (unless you mean the food), and you actually want log(1-(-1))=log(2) rather than log(1-1/2)=log(1/2). The answer is pi/4 - 1/2 log(2). In addition, you haven't justified why you're allowed to split the infinite series like that. In fact, since OP only asked for convergence, that's probably the most important part.

Comment: In LaTeX: The answer is $\dfrac\pi4-\dfrac12\log(2)$.

Answer (score 1):

Take alternating harmonic series and add $ (-2/3 ) + ( 2/4) + (-2/7) + (2/8)+......$ both alternating harmonic series and the added series are converging.