# Convergence of $1+\frac13-\frac12+\frac15+\frac17-\frac14+\frac19+\frac1{11}-\frac16+\ldots$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

I was reading Rudin PMA, example 3.53 on P76. There he points out that rearrangement may not give same limit of a series. Then he says that it is left as exercise to show that above mentioned series converges. I thought clubbing three terms, but did not seem 'legal'.

> How to show that series $1+\dfrac13-\dfrac12+\dfrac15+\dfrac17-\dfrac14+\dfrac19+\dfrac1{11}-\dfrac16+\ldots$ converges?

I tried root test: Let this series be $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_n$, then $\limsup\limits_{n\to\infty}\sqrt[n]{|a_n|}=1$, since basically, this series is rearrangement of $\sum \frac {(-1)^n}n$. So root test is inconclusive.

Comment: Isn't just a rearrangement of $\displaystyle\frac{(-1)^n}{n}$ that converges for Leibniz?

Comment: Hint: Compute an equivalent of the $k$th block of three consecutive terms.

Comment: @edo1998 But $\frac{(-1)^n}n$ doesn't converge absolutely, so rearrangements may change the convergence.

Comment: What is the general term of this series?

Comment: Yes, you are right, it is not decreasing!

Comment: How exactly is this series defined? What is the 1000-th term of this series? What is the $n$-th term?

Comment: Why is it that 99 out of 100 persons talking about an infinite series wouldn't be able or willing to tell you the definition of convergence, but they will remember (a mutilated version of) the ratio test or the root test? Both tests are (even in their correct form) mostly useless outside the context of power series and their radius of convergence.

Comment: @ProfessorVector Probably because it's the first test you learn when doing series. I mean, the test is easy to calculate so it usually doesn't hurt to try it, even though it usually doesn't work :)

Comment: BTW, it's easy to check that the partial sum of the first $3n$ terms is $\displaystyle H_{4n}-\frac12\,H_{2n}-\frac12\,H_n\to\ln4-\frac12\,\ln2=\frac32\,\ln2$.

Comment: Far and away the best answer, @ProfessorVector.

Comment: @ancientmathematician No, it's a comment, because I'm at work and don't have the time for a real answer.

Comment: Similar to, but not the same as, [Prove $1-\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{5}-\frac{1}{6}-\frac{1}{7}+\cdots$ converges.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/712413/prove-1-frac12-frac13-frac14-frac15-frac16-frac17).

Comment: This is not unclear, but the context is minimal. Unfortunately, there was one vote to close citing "lack of context" and two votes citing "unclear what you're asking" so the reason came through as unclear.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In blocks of $3$ terms, the series is
$$
\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \left(\dfrac{1}{4n+1}+\dfrac{1}{4n+3}-\dfrac{1}{2n+2}\right)
=
\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \dfrac{8 n + 5}{32 n^3 + 64 n^2 + 38 n + 6}
\le
\dfrac56+
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \dfrac{1}{n^2}
< \infty
$$

This proves that the partial sums $S_{3n+2}$ of the original series converge. The other partial sums, $S_{3n+1}$ and  $S_{3n}$, differ from $S_{3n+2}$ by one or two terms that converge to zero and so they converge as well, to the same limit. Thus, the partial sums converge, that is, the series converges.

Comment: Also I thought this was a valid reasoning at first, I now came to the conclusion that you are not allowed to group alternating series like that. E.g. by the same reasoning one can argue that $\sum (-1)^n$ converges to zero by grouping $\sum (1+(-1))$. You can group only positive terms, or only negative terms, but not mixed.

Comment: @M.Winter, if the terms tend to $0$, which they don't for $\sum(-1)^n$, then you *are* allowed to group a bounded number (in this case three) of terms at a time.

Comment: @BarryCipra I see. Thanks for this enlightenment. I think this is a non-trivial part of the reasoning and should be at least mentioned in the answer. Otherwise one might think this is generally valid (it took me some thinking to get this and I think it needs a proof or a name which can be googled).

Comment: @M.Winter, see my edited answer. Thanks for the nudge.

Comment: @lhf, I think you are using comparison test, but [this](https://www.symbolab.com/solver/step-by-step/%5Cfrac%7B8%20n%20%2B%205%7D%7B32%20n%5E%7B3%7D%20%2B%2064%20n%5E%7B2%7D%20%2B%2038%20n%20%2B%206%7D%3C%5Cfrac%7B1%7D%7Bn%5E%7B2%7D%7D) says that $\frac{8\:n\:+\:5}{32\:n^3\:+\:64\:n^2\:+\:38\:n\:+\:6}<\frac{1}{n^2}$ holds for no $n$

Comment: @Silent, I'm not sure how symolab works, but the conclusion you've drawn is most decidedly wrong. If nothing else, just plug in $n=1$ and check that the inequality holds.

Comment: So sorry @BarryCipra, Thanks for pointing that out! I need one more help though: It is very  new point to me which you mentioned [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2663152/convergence-of-1-frac13-frac12-frac15-frac17-frac14-frac19-frac111-fr#comment5500982_2663169), and seems to be very powerful, since we have to look at a subsequence of partial sums. Can you give a link that has proof of this statement? Also, what does bounded mean there?

Comment: @Silent, it's been time since I've looked at how any textbooks present the elementary theory of infinite series, so I can't give any references. Maybe someone else can.  As for "bounded number of terms," note that $$1-1+{1\over2}+{1\over2}-{1\over2}-{1\over2}+{1\over3}+{1\over3}+{1\over3}-{1\over3}-{1\over3}-{1\over3}+\cdots$$ fails to converge even though the terms are tending to $0$ and $$(1-1)+({1\over2}+{1\over2}-{1\over2}-{1\over2})+({1\over3}+{1\over3}+{1\over3}-{1\over3}-{1\over3}-{1\over3})+\cdots=0+0+0+\cdots$$ makes it look convergent.

Answer (score 3):

It seems like the series is alternatingly composed of positive terms (and it is okay to group them) of the form

$$a_{2n}=\frac1{4n+1}+\frac1{4n+3}=\frac{8n+4}{(4n+1)(4n+3)}=\frac{8n+4}{16n^2+16n+3}=\frac{n+1/2}{2n^2+2n+3/8}.$$

for $n=0,1,2,...$, and negative terms of the form

$$a_{2n+1}=-\frac{1}{2n+2}.$$

also for $n=0,1,2,...$. Note that for sufficiently large $n$ we have

$$
\underbrace{\frac1{2n}}_{|a_{2n-1}|}
\ge \underbrace{\frac{n+1/2}{2n^2+2n+3/8}}_{|a_{2n}|}
\ge \underbrace{\frac 1{2n+2}}_{|a_{2n+1}|}.
$$

So we have an alternating series with absolutely decreasing terms with $|a_n|\to 0$. We can apply the [alternating series test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alternating_series_test) to reason that the sum converges.

Answer (score 2):

As many people already pointed out, the series converges thanks to Leibniz criterion! Indeed the series is
$$ \sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^{n+1} a_n, $$
where $a_n$ are
$$ a_n = \begin{cases}
\frac{1}{n} & n\ \text{even,}\\
\frac{1}{n+n-1}+ \frac{1}{n+2+n-1} = \frac{1}{2n-1}+\frac{1}{2n+1} & n \ \text{odd,}
\end{cases} \qquad a_n \to 0. $$

Answer (score 0):

$c_1 := 1+\frac{1}{3}$.
$c_2 := -\frac{1}{2}$.
$c_3 := \frac{1}{5} + \frac{1}{7}$.
$c_4 := -\frac{1}{4}$.
$c_5 := \frac{1}{9} + \frac{1}{11}$.
$c_6 := -\frac{1}{6}$.
$\cdots$
$c_{2 k - 1} := \frac{1}{4 k - 3} + \frac{1}{4 k - 1}$ for $k \in \{1, 2, 3, \cdots\}$.
$c_{2 k} := -\frac{1}{2 k}$ for $k \in \{1, 2, 3, \cdots\}$.

Then,
(a)
$\frac{1}{4 k - 3} + \frac{1}{4 k - 1} > \frac{1}{4 k} + \frac{1}{4 k} > \frac{1}{4 k + 1} + \frac{1}{4 k + 3}$.
$\therefore |c_{2 k - 1}| > |c_{2 k}| > |c_{2 k + 1}|$ for $k \in \{1, 2, 3, \cdots\}$.

(b)
$c_{2 k - 1} \geq 0$ and $c_{2 k} \leq 0$.

(c)
$\lim_{k\to\infty} c_{2 k - 1} = \lim_{k\to\infty} c_{2 k} = 0$.
$\therefore \lim_{n\to\infty} c_n = 0$.

So, $\sum c_n$ is an alternating series and converges by Theorem 3.43 on p.71.

$c_1 = s'_2$.
$c_1 + c_2 = s'_3$.
$c_1 + c_2 + c_3 = s'_5$.
$c_1 + c_2 + c_3 + c_4 = s'_6$.
$c_1 + c_2 + c_3 + c_4 + c_5 = s'_8$.
$c_1 + c_2 + c_3 + c_4 + c_5 + c_6= s'_9$.
$\cdots$

So, $s'_2, s'_3, s'_5, s'_6, s'_8, s'_9, \cdots$ is a convergent subsequence of $\{s'_n\}$.
So, $s'_2, s'_5, s'_8, s'_{11}, \cdots$ is a convergent subsequence of $\{s'_n\}$.
$s'_{3 k - 2} = s'_{3 k - 1} - \frac{1}{4 k - 1}$.
So, $s'_1, s'_4, s'_7, s'_{10}, \cdots$ is a convergent subsequence of $\{s'_n\}$.
$\{s'_1, s'_4, s'_7, s'_{10}, \cdots\} \cup \{s'_2, s'_3, s'_5, s'_6, s'_8, s'_9, \cdots \} = \{s'_1, s'_2, s'_3, s'_4, s'_5, s'_6, s'_7, s'_8, s'_9, s'_{10}, \cdots\}$.
So, $\{s'_n\}$ converges.

Comment: I wrote this answer for my memo. Is my answer correct?